# ASP.NET form not submitting

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

When I click submit, the page is refreshed and looks like everything went through, but is not hitting the ActionResult I am trying to send it to.

I've tried submitting normally and with JavaScript and neither will work.

```html
<form method="post" autocomplete="off" asp-controller="Default" asp-action="Submit">
    <button id="SubmitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller Method:

```cs
namespace (Removed).Controllers
{
    public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Submit()
        {
            DBController1 DB1 = new DBController1();
            AlertManagement am = new AlertManagement();

            am.FirstName = Request.Form["FirstName"];
            am.LastName = Request.Form["LastName"];
            am.Email = Request.Form["EmailAddress"];
            am.Mobile = Request.Form["PhoneNumber"].Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");
            am.Affiliation = Request.Form["Affiliation"];
            am.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["StartDate"]).Date;
            am.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["EndDate"]).Date;

            DB1.AlertManagement.Add(am);
            DB1.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the RouteConfig:

```cs
namespace (Removed)
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Index",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Submit",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Submit", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

When I click submit, it always goes to ActionResult Index()

Comment: What does your controller and method look like?

Comment: @MatthewEvans I've added it.

Comment: In a class called DefaultController ?

Comment: Recommend Phil Haacked's routing debugger for these; https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/

Comment: @MatthewEvans I've added the entire controller now.

Comment: as answered below, if you are not using model binding, you need to parameterize your method with FromForm values matching your POST data, so that the signature is matched, otherwise it wont be invoked. Again routedebugger will tell you what's going on

Answer (score 1):

Taking a shot in the dark here, but does your controller look like this?

```
public class DefaultController: Controller
    {
        [HttpPost] // This attribute states that this action result can only be accessed when using http POST verb.
        public IActionResult Submit()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }

    }
```

Also, what are you posting? If you have intentionally left out the fields in your example make sure that in your POST method you have this.

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off" asp-controller="Default" asp-action="Submit">
<input type="text" name="nameOfElement" id="clientName" />
    <button id="SubmitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
    public class DefaultController: Controller
            {
                [HttpPost] 
                public IActionResult Submit([FromForm] string nameOfElement)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
                }

            }
```

Comment: DefaultController , not Default ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, meant DefaultController. I have fixed my post.

Comment: I've purposely left out all the inputs, but they are all there. I have posted my controller so you can see what I have. Instead of submitting to Submit(), it goes to Index().

Comment: and the [HttpPost]  attribute?

Comment: And if you add a break point inside that method, does it hit?

Comment: Have you added the [HttpPost] attribute to your submit action ?

Comment: I see your Sibmit() redirects to Index(), have you tried adding a break point as well ? just to see whats happening ?

Comment: This might not help but have you tried changing from ActionResult to IActionResult ?

Comment: I also noticed that your route named Submit has the same signature as you Index route. Try removing the maped route named submit and try again.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form action="/Default/Submit" method="post">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

the ActionMethod you are expecting to be called is of Verb 'GET' while your Form submit method type is 'POST'
add HttpPost attribute it shouls work

```
 [HttpPost]
Public ActionResult Submit()
{
}
```

Comment: How is this related to OP's question, and why do you think your code snippet solves the issue?

Comment: look at his actionmethod  is does not have any Http verb so by default is is GET while his Form is excepting a Post method. he will get an 404 error.

Comment: Not my downvote, but one issue is that in OP's post the controller is named Default, not Controller as in your example.